# Xcode open files in separate tab always, like VSCode

Tags: xcode

I find that I am spending a remarkable amount of time looking for files just to open something that I had open a second ago.

The issue is that every time I click on a file on the left hand side, the file in the editor is *replaced* by the selected file. This means I end up spending 15 seconds every time I need to go look at the old file just searching for it. I've never seen any other editor do this save for Xcode. The way all other editors work (Eclipse, vscode, sublime, vim) is if you have a file open and are working on it, and open a new file, it opens the new file in a new tab. This saves you the trouble that I'm going through right now.

An alternative is to right-click every time and "open in a new tab", but I forget to do that every time.

Is there any option that I can change to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `Xcode / Preferences / Navigation / Double Click Navigation / Uses Separate Tab`:

[image: navigation]

This way, double-click a file opens it in a new tab.

For a single-click option, you could use the first drop-down `Optional Navigation`. But then you would need to press <kbd>Option</kbd> + click to open the file in a new tab.

Comment: So now he needs to remember to double click instead?